# Different Processing rendering between native and online sketch

Tags: processing, open-source, p5.js, processing.js

I get different results when running this sample with Processing directly, and with Processing.js in a browser. Why?

I was happy about my result and wanted to share it on open Processing, but the rendering was totally different and I don't see why. Below is a minimal working example.

```
/* Program that rotates a triange and draws an ellipse when the third vertex is on top of the screen*/

float y = 3*height/2;
float x = 3*width/2;

float previous_1 = 0.0;
float previous_2 = 0.0;
float current;
float angle = 0.0;


void setup() {
  size(1100, 500);
}

void draw() {

  fill(0, 30);

  // rotate triangle
  angle = angle - 0.02;
  translate(x, y); 
  rotate(angle); 

  // display triangle
  triangle(-50, -50, -30, 30, -90, -60);

  // detect whether third vertex is on top by comparing its 3 successive positions
  current = screenY(-90, -60); // current position of the third vertex

  if (previous_1 < previous_2 && previous_1 < current) {
    // draw ellipse at the extrema position
    fill(128, 9, 9);
    ellipse(-90, -60, 7, 10); 
  }

  // update the 2 previous positions of the third vertex
  previous_2 = previous_1;
  previous_1 = current;
}
```

- In processing, the ellipse is drawn when a triangle vertex is on top, which is my goal.
- In online sketching, the ellipse is drawn during the whole time :/

Comment: Please be aware that processing.js was retired in December 2018. Don't write code with it. Also note that it is not the same project as p5js, which very much _is_ still maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the same results online as you get by running Processing locally you will need to specify the rendering mode as 3d when calling [size](https://processing.org/reference/size_.html)

For example:

```
void setup() {
  size(1100, 500, P3D);
}
```

You will also need to specify the z coordinate in the call to `screenY()`

```
current = screenY(-90, -60, 0);
```

With these two changes you should get the same results online as you get running locally.

Online:

[Triangle Ellipse Example](https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/691903)

Local:

[image: Triangle Ellipse Exampl]

Comment: Glad to help and welcome to stackoverflow. Be sure and upvote all helpful answers and mark the answer that best answers the question as accepted. Voting and accepting will help others find good questions and answers.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the `screenY` function. Print out the `current` variable in your processing sketch locally and online. In OpenProcessing, the variable `current` grows quickly above multiple thousands, while it stays between 0 and ~260 locally.

It seems like OpenProcessing has a bug inside this function.

To fix this however, I would recommend you to register differently when you drew a triangle at the top of the circle, for example by using your angle variable:

```
// Calculate angle and modulo it by 2 * PI
angle = (angle - 0.02) % (2 * PI);

// If the sketch has made a full revolution
if (previous_1 < previous_2 && previous_1 < angle) {
    // draw ellipse at the extrema position
    fill(128, 9, 9);
    ellipse(-90, -60, 7, 10); 
}

// update the 2 previous angles of the third vertex
previous_2 = previous_1;
previous_1 = angle;
```

However, because of how you draw the triangles, the ellipse is at an angle of about `PI / 3`. To fix this, one option would be to rotate the screen by `angle + PI / 3` like so:

```
rotate(angle + PI / 3);
```

You might have to experiment with the angle offset a bit more to draw the ellipse perfectly at the top of the circle.